# css hover does not work for col in my html

Tags: html, css

I have used django to develop a web app. I want to achieve this function: when mouse on hover on the img col, it should be shadowed.
However, I got some error, which is very confused, my css could not function at all, there's no change after mouse move.
HTML:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<style>
.col:hover{
  -o-transition:.5s  !important ;
  -ms-transition:.5s !important;
  -moz-transition:.5s !important;
  -webkit-transition:.5s !important;
  transition:.5s;  !important
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888 !important;
}
</style>
        <!-- Content Row -->
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-xl-stretch justify-content-between mb-4">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Content Checklist</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

                                                            <a href="{% url 'bms:new_content_checklist' %}">
    <span  STYLE="font-size:600%'">
        <img src="{% static 'image/new_cc.png' %}">
    </span></a>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

                                            <a href="{% url 'bms:content_checklist_discipline' %}">
    <span  STYLE="font-size:600%'">
        <img src="{% static 'image/extract_discipline.png' %}">
    </span></a>


            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">

                            <a href="{% url 'bms:courseinfo_list' %}">
    <span  STYLE="font-size:600%'">
        <img src="{% static 'image/extract_course.png' %}">
    </span></a>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">


            <a href="{% url 'bms:emailinfo_list' %}">
    <span  STYLE="font-size:600%'">
        <img src="{% static 'image/email_templates.png' %}">
    </span></a>

            </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The hover style in css could not work for my page.

I have tried to replace .col with .img. still could not work after ctrl+f5

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please convert your code (just htlm and css NOT the template code) snippet to a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Grumpy No error , but nothing happened when I move the mouse

Comment: `transition:.5s;  !important` is invalid CSS, invalidating your whole ruleset. `transition:.5s  !important;`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have a syntax error with your "!important"
It needs to be within the semi-colon.

You are also missing a closing  tag for your "col" div.

To create a transition effect, you must specify two things:

1. the CSS property you want to add an effect to
2. the duration of the effect

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

You need to specify what you are trying to transition.

Change this line from:

```
transition:.5s;  !important
```

to

```
transition: box-shadow .5s!important;
```

And finally, I suggest you inspect the col element in your browser with hover, and see that the box-shadow is being applied.

[image]

It could be something like the element directly below it sitting on top of, and blocking the shadow from being seen.

Comment: I used ur solution, still nothing happened when I move the mouse, any duration and any shadow change are ok for me, but now nothing happened

Comment: you are also missing a closing </div> tag

Comment: that would not affect on anything for chrome, right? I added it. still not working

Comment: the code and syntax will definitely work within the context of html/css. so it will be other elements at play - it's hard to know without a reproduction of the issue.

Comment: last thing i suggest is inspecting in chrome and seeing if the css is applied when you hover. if it is, it could be what i described where the element below is blocking the shadow. otherwise, you'll have to look outside of the provided context, because i can confirm that in vanilla html/css the transition works

Comment: how to inspecting in chrome and seeing if the css is applied when hover?

Comment: you inspect the 'col' div and click the buttons (in my screenshot) to simulate hover.. then see if the transitions css shows up

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you have an error in your styling. when it comes to styles, the browser is very forgiving and simply ignores what it cannot understand.

```css
.col:hover {
  -o-transition: .5s !important;
  -ms-transition: .5s !important;
  -moz-transition: .5s !important;
  -webkit-transition: .5s !important;
  transition: .5s !important; /* Fixed the semicolon position. */
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-xl-stretch justify-content-between mb-4">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Content Checklist</h1>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
        <a href="#">
            <span>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x20">
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for the `!important` part, I don't know for the rest of your code, but I advise using this only as a last resort, because this is not a preferred method of setting styles. usually you can resolve style conflicts with a better defined selector.